# JMeter: Recording tests without proxy server

Tags: jmeter, proxy-server

At the place where I am working, proxy settings are not allowed.  Is there any way by which I could record HTTP sessions and use them in JMeter during replay?

Comment: Why aren't proxys allowed?  What is the network topology of the site such that you can't use a proxy to hit the site? What are you trying to test if you can't hit the site through a proxy? What does your JMeter configuration look like?

Comment: Thanks Michael.The issue is only IE is allowed and under Tools>Internet Options, Connections tab is not visible. JMeter configuration is normal wherein I can add samplers ,listeners and all

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which allows HTTP Requests and associated cookies, headers, think times, etc. recording right from browser without having to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.

Another option is using [BadBoy](http://www.badboy.com.au/recording.html) software which can export scripts to JMeter.

However there should not be any problem to launch a JMeter proxy on your workstation as it doesn't broadcast anything hence shouldn't be visible.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. The challenge is I have to work with IE alone and the Connections tab is not visible in Internet Options.Is there a free tool which can record and then I could export those http sessions to JMeter.Also how to export them.I guess BadBoy is not totally free.Is Fiddler an option?

Comment: It should be possible, at least there is a possibility to create JMeter exporting plugin and add it to Fiddler http://www.perftesting.co.uk/creating-jmeter-test-plans-with-fiddler/2013/03/01/ 

For Badboy: `For-profit organizations using Badboy with more than five users are required to purchase licenses.` so if the number of Badboy users in you company is <= 5 you should be fine to use Badboy software free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly which browser you are using, if using chrome use BlazeMeter chrome extension, download it from google it is free

Secondly if using forefox use the configure the recording controller in your test plan and then use HTTP test script recorder it will work